# Unable to replicate fuse sshfs setup, with regular sshfs command

Tags: automounting, sshfs

**Goal: mount remote folder via sshfs on local system on boot**

I have an empty USB attached to my machine: `/media/steve/downloads-remote/`
There is one folder inside the drive `Downloads`
The permissions of the drive and the folder are: `drwxrwxrwx`

When I run this command: `sshfs steve@sub.example.com:/mnt/mpathw/steve/Downloads /media/steve/downloads-remote/Downloads -o allow_other,reconnect`

The drive is mounted, and the two directories are linked. I can see folders, add/remove edit on both sides and everything works as expected.

**Now I am trying to achieve the same thing, but have this drive mounted on boot permanently.**

I have edited `fuse.conf` and added: `user_allow_other`

Then I have edited my `fstab` file and added this:

```
steve@sub.example.com:/mnt/mpathw/steve/Downloads  /media/steve/downloads-remote/Downloads  fuse.sshfs  allow_other,identityfile=/home/steve/.ssh/id_rsa,default_permissions,idmap=user,reconnect,uid=1000,gid=1000  0  0
```

Now, after rebooting my system:

First it creates another mounting point, so that my media folder suddenly looks like this:

```
/media/steve
--downloads-remote
--downloads-remote1/Downloads
```

My original `/Downloads` folder has now been pushed onto `downloads-remote1`

When I try to access `/media/steve/downloads-remote/` I get **Permission Denied**.

When I check the permissions of `/media/steve/downloads-remote/` I see `drwx------ 3 root root`.

I then changed the permissions with: `sudo chmod -R a+rwx downloads-remote`, so now permissions look like this: `drwxrwxrwx 3 root root`

Now I can enter into `/media/amir/downloads-remote/Downloads`, however, there are no files there, it is not synced with the remote server.

What is missing from my setup?

1. I don't want it to create this new directory `downloads-remote1`, I want it mounted just like I have it when I use `sshfs` directly. `/media/steve/downloads-remote/Downloads`
2. Why does is it assigning the folder to root and making me change the permissions?
3. Why does it not seem to be actually connected to the remote drive, since I can't see any of the files/folders.

Comment: You should be able to fix some things by adding option `_netdev` to the fstab entry, so systemd waits until the network is available.

Comment: @meuh I've added `_netdev`, now everything is the same, except now it also mount `/media/steve/downloads-remote/Downloads`. Before it was only going to `/media/steve/downloads-remote`, but everything is still the same. 2 folders created, and neither is syncing with remote.

Comment: `man systemd.mount` seems to say that many dependencies are automatically determined and create `After=` in the created Unit. However, you could try explicitly adding option `x-systemd.requires-mounts-for=/media/steve/downloads-remote`. Also, try looking in the logs, perhaps with `sudo systemctl status media-steve-downloads\x2dremote-Downloads.mount` or all of them `sudo systemctl status '*'.mount`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I couldn't get it to work. There are issues with authentication, checking logs, it seems like at times it tires to connect before eth is up...sometimes it's some other error.. in any case way to much troube for what I'm trying to do.

In the end I just created a bash script that ran on startup and ran the `sshfs`line